# Ubuntu 22.04 black screen

Tags: 22.04, suspend, login-screen

I do have dual boot in my laptop(HP core i5 8th gen).Ubuntu goes black screen for inactivity and does not wake up.Even the login screen goes black after loading.I tried to increase the sleep time and its not working.How to fix this issue.
TIA.

Comment: This sounds like it may be graphics card related. Can you give any details on what graphics hardware you have in the laptop? Also, this may be helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405262/how-to-solve-black-screen-after-suspension-with-ubuntu-22-04-lts

Comment: I have Nvidia 940MX.

Comment: It may be you need to find out whether a specific driver needs to be installed for that. Try following the instructions here to see if that helps https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation or try upgrading or downgrading using the "additional drivers" tab in "software & updates".

Comment: I installed Nvidia driver according to the guidelines and my Login screen doesn't even appear.

Comment: Uninstalled nvidia drivers and Now I can log in to ubuntu.but the above problem of black screen due to inactivity still appears.